# Authenticate user by url querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to authenticate an user based on a querystring parameter.
I've created a custom AuthorizeAttribute that overrides AuthorizeCore method to decode\validate the querystring parameter, call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() and returns true if it's valid and it works as expected (the user can access secured area)

However the controller decorated with my custom AuthorizeAttribute cannot access user's data via Membership.GetUser(), I think because the request is still not authenticated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried validating the query string and rather than rolling your own authentication, just calling the base.AuthorizeCore when you have populated the properties on the User object?

Comment: Nope, could you please explain me that way?